# mvc data annotation causing model to go invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a class `UserUtil` and I added some Data annotation. This is affecting my login causing my model to go invalid.

```
public partial class UserUtil
{
    public int cod_ap { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Password")]
    [Required]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Email")]
    [Required]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ContorUtil ContorUtil { get; set; }
}
```

this is my login Method. ModelState is invalid

```
public ActionResult LogIn(Models.Entity.UserUtil utilizator)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var v = db.UserUtils.Where(a => a.UserEmail.Equals(utilizator.UserEmail) && a.UserPassword.Equals(utilizator.UserPassword)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            Session["LoggedUsername"] = v.UserEmail.ToString();
            Session["cod_ap"] = v.cod_ap.ToString();
            //Session["LoggedUserPassword"] = v.UserPassword.ToString();

            if (Session["cod_ap"].ToString() == "11111")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
            }

        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that at login i use only 2 members of the class UserEmail  and UserPassword  and the model is invalid cus the other one is null...but how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `UserUtil` is an entity class. You need to create a separate view model class with only `UserEmail` and `UserPassword` properties, then use the view model in your view. Let's say it's named LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [DisplayName("User Email")]
    [Required]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Password")]
    [Required]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Add this at the top of your view code

```
@model LoginModel
```

and change your controller code to below

```
public ActionResult LogIn(LoginModel utilizator)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var v = db.UserUtils.Where(a => a.UserEmail.Equals(utilizator.UserEmail) && a.UserPassword.Equals(utilizator.UserPassword)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            Session["LoggedUsername"] = v.UserEmail.ToString();
            Session["cod_ap"] = v.cod_ap.ToString();
            //Session["LoggedUserPassword"] = v.UserPassword.ToString();

            if (Session["cod_ap"].ToString() == "11111")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
            }

        }
    }
    return View();
}
```